# Disable modification to plain text editor

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qplaintextedit

I try to do a terminal in pyqt5 using plain text editor. This terminal should print some output but also should take some inputes from users.

My question is how can we disable modifications (but not just set in readOnly mode) for plain text editor when enter is pressed?

What I try to do is to allow users to enter some commande lines but
prevent them to modify past input or output from the soft.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to make a specific part of a `QPlainTextEdit` editable while the rest is read only?

Comment: yes exactly. i want to make a part read only when i push enter